# Js, Jquery and other scripts loaded but don´t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I am trying to make a web using js, jquery, nvd3, etc... As they are a lot of libraries and script files I decided to surf the web and look for a way of loading them in the correct order so as not to have any dependencies errors.

I found this code which is compatible with most of the browsers and, in theory, should work. Apparently it works correctly because the scripts are listed as loaded in the network tag of Chrome and the console doesn´t show anything (apart from the messages I was expecting) but the web doesn´t do what was expected:

```
        function addEvent(element, event, fn) {
        if (element.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
        } else if (element.attachEvent) {
            element.attachEvent('on' + event, fn);
        }
    }

    function loadScript(src, callback)
    {
        console.log("cargando");
      var s,
          r,
          t,
          write;

      write = src.split("/");

      // this is useless. It's just for an animation
      //document.getElementById('loadingContent').innerHTML = 'Loading ... ' + write[(write.length - 1)] + ' ... ';

      r = false;
      s = document.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.src = src;
      s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( !r && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'complete') )
        {
          r = true;
          if (callback !== undefined) {
            callback();
          }
        }
      };
      t = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t);
    }

    addEvent(window, 'load', function(){ loadScript(
            'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js', 
            function () { 
                loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js',
                    function () {
                       loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.1.15-beta/nv.d3.min.js',
                       function() {
                         loadScript('/static/js/jquery-ui.min.js'), 
                         function() {
                             loadScript('/static/js/chart.js');
                         };


                       }); 
                    });
            });
    });

    function mensaje() {
        console.log("LOADED");
    }

    mensaje()
```

One of the weirdest things I saw is that the last function (the "mensage" one) prints it's console log the first one inspite of being the last!

Here is my html code (the "strange" things are django tags). I left the css files with no reason (probably as soon as I can make this work I will include them in the loading script):

```
        {% extends "pvpc/base.html" %}

    {% block title %}<title>Consumo</title>{% endblock %}

    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% block scripts %}
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.1.15-beta/nv.d3.min.css" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/jquery-ui.min.css" %}">
        <script src="{% static "js/load_plus.js" %}"></script>

    {% endblock %}

    {% block header %}<h1>CONSUMO</h1>{% endblock %}

    {% block section %}
    </head>
    <body>
      <form>
      <div id="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="1"><label for="radio1">2.0A</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="2"><label for="radio2">2.0DHA</label> <!-- <input checked="checked"> -->
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" value="3"><label for="radio3">2.0DHS</label>
      </div>
    </form>
    <p>

      <label for="amount">Periodo horario:</label>
      <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
    </p>
    <p id="slider"></p>

    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="date" name="Fecha">

    <div id="piechart"><svg></svg></div>
    <div id="chart"><svg></svg></div>

    </body>
    </html>
     {% endblock section %}
```

I am really lost with this because I tried evrything but can´t find the error...
I think it has to be some small thing that makes everything not to work.

Comment: _"but the web doesn´t do what was expected"_ isn't descriptive of what your actual problem is, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Basically nothing, if I knew don´t you think I would have fixed it?

Comment: How do you know it's broken then if you don't know what isn't working? For example, are the scripts not executing, or are the objects created in the scripts not accessible (ie you cannot use the jQuery object)

Comment: Finally I found a typo and everything worked again. Sorry but I am a noob programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `mensaje` function be called when everything is loaded, so you need to call it on the charts.js line like this:
`loadScript('/static/js/chart.js', mensaje);` (instead of the original code).

And you want to remove the line `mensaje()` at the end of the script because it will call `mensaje` and display 'LOADED' before everything is loaded.

Comment: Why? I thought the scripts were loaded from the top to the bottom while they were executed!

Comment: The loadScript function sends an asynchronous request. It loads the script but it is uncertain beforehand when the script will be done loading. To not block the website until the complete script file is loaded it will open a new side process that will call the function provided as second argument when it is done. This function can (and probably will) therefore be executed after the end of the rest of the code has been reached.

Comment: I tried to understand a little bit more how this works and I used the message function as callback of the last scripts load. It keeps showing the message before the script is loaded!  i don´t catch it...

Answer (score 0):

The js resources are probably cached by your browser. reloading using Ctrl+F5 is to refresh the cache. open your every js file in the browser and refresh that page by `ctrl+F5`. It should work.

Comment: if it doesn't work on initial page load why would it work on a reload? Doesn't make sense

Comment: the css and js resources are probably cached by his browser. reloading using Ctrl+F5 is to refresh the cache in that reload.

Comment: well if that is your assumption you should explain it in the answer that it could be a cache problem although I suspect the issue is deeper than that